# What is an example of zero exponent in nature?

Tags: exponentiation

This concept is difficult for non-professionals to grasp, and I admit that I can't even conceive of how this exists in nature, as opposed to proving that 2+2=4 by a more traditional explanation such as grouping objects together.

Does some number taken to the zero power exist in nature?  If so, please describe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. If you have an exponential function to, for instance, describe a population that doubles daily and starts at $a$
$$p(x) = a2^x$$

then taking $2^0$, should naturally equal $1$, because at time $0$, the population is exactly the starting population $a$.

Comment: Of course!  Can you think of any others?  Thank you!

Comment: @WannabeHolyPerson, look at these: https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~evans/PHYS-Skills/Exponentials%20in%20Physics.pdf
For all of them, try setting the variable in the exponent to $0$, then think about the physical implications of doing that (no time passed, the obstacle has no thickness, etc.)

Comment: A population of Covid-19 infected people, with $2^0$ people infected on day 0 (bad joke sorry)

Comment: @RüdiJehn sadly, that was probably enough...

Answer (score 0):

In the case of radioactive [decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay), the amount of non-decayed substance is

$$f(t)=A2^{-\frac{t}{T}}$$

where $A$ is the initial quantity, $t$ is time, and $T$ is the [half-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life) of the decay. Plugging $t=0$ yields $f(0)=A$, the initial quantity, as expected.